# Sql server missing index shows columns already contained in another index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-administration

I have a table `Employees(Id,CompanyId,Name,Status....)`
I have an index `Ix_CompanyId_Status(CompanyId,Status)`

looking on the `dm_db_missing_index_details`, I see that sql server wants an index on `CompanyId` in equality columns without any inequality columns or included columns.

why is this index needed if it's data is already included in the index mentioned above?

Comment: That code behind the *missing index DMV" isn't the best in SQL Server - there is a chance it will suggest an index is missing, even though it's already there - sometimes it'll even suggest the exact same index that's already in place. Those recommendations have to be taken with a grain of salt - don't just blindly create all those indexes! As you did: check to see if the recommendation is valid and makes sense - and if not, as in your case - just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CompanyID is a foreign key you may get it as a suggested index from 
`dm_db_missing_index_details`.

Comment: indeed CompanyId is a foreign key (to the companies table). can I still safely ignore the suggestion?

Comment: I usually use Index for my foreign keys because I am most likely joining on it and not having indexes will slow down the query.And also you should be careful about deleting companies from the parent table.

Comment: but if I have an index on CompanyId and another column, won't this index be good for the table joining in queries? should I specifically add an index on the FK?

Comment: I've really never done this before but I think in this case it will be OK not to add an extra index for FK.(it's only a guess)

Comment: thanks. I will try to check if it has any influence using the actual query plan in SSMS

Comment: It became question for myself too, so I asked it again check answers to my post too, [Having Indexes on two column including one FK,Is it ok not having Index on FK itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361178/having-indexes-on-two-column-including-one-fk-is-it-ok-not-having-index-on-fk-it/13362855#13362855)